# MySQL shortest query without results

Tags: mysql

I'm looking for a query with the lowest possible resource usage which gives no result. For example (this won't work):

```
SELECT 1 WHERE 0
```

**Edit:**
The goal would be to be used in an EXISTS subquery in special cases where I want no matches. (I know this is not the only possible solution, but in my environment I chose to use this one).

Comment: Why don't you change the `WHERE EXISTS (no result subquery)` to `WHERE FALSE` ?

Comment: @ypercube The exists subquery is somthimes used in conjuction with other exists subqueries like `WHERE EXISTS (no result) OR EXISTS (other)`. It definitely needs refactoring down the road, but now, it it the safest solution (with the least possibility of introducing bugs).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL WHERE 0
```

will do the job; you will not even need a USE-statement before.

Comment: Thanks this did the trick. Though previously I dismissed `SELECT * FROM (SELECT 1) AS a WHERE 0` because of the stupid GUI I use showed very misleading results...

Comment: `SELECT * FROM (SELECT 1) AS a WHERE 0` is valid solution, too.

Answer (score 3):

```
select '1' from tableName where 0
```

Comment: This involves loading a table, I would like to avoid it, for low resource usage.

Comment: @vbence - what is this for? It's would be a lot easier to help if we knew

Comment: @vbence: This is valid solution too. It does NOT load the table. Try `EXPLAIN SELECT 1 FROM tableName WHERE 0` to see why.

Comment: Thanks, this is also a good solution. But I still find the `DUAL` version best because it is more general.

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT 1`; would work but it gives a result set
You could try `SELECT NULL from <any table>`
A `USE <database name>` statement gives no result and takes up minimal resources.

What is this for exactly?

Comment: SELECT 1 would return results though. Your USE db answer could be correct though it isn't a query.

Comment: I would also like to know "What is this for exactly?"

Comment: The problem with USE is that it can not be used as a (sub)query.

Comment: @vbence: Hmmm.. What is this for exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could do

```
select 1 where 1=0
```

Comment: No, I can not use WHERE if no table is loaded.